# Underscore's .defer() in Backbone Results in Error: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using `defer()` in two places within the same Backbone View, to run two different functions.  However, both result in the error included below:

**The Two Function Calls are located within the Render Function:**

```
loadReferralCollection: function(collection) {
        console.log("hello")
},

loadRemixedCollection: function(collection) {
        console.log("hello")
},

render: function() {
        var self = this;
        if ( this.options.params !== undefined && this.options.params.referral !== undefined ){
              _( self.loadReferralCollection(self.model) ).defer();
        } else if ( this.options.params !== undefined && this.options.params.remix !== undefined ) {
              _( self.loadRemixedCollection(self.model) ).defer();
        }
}
```

**The Full Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined underscore.js?body=1:621
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

defer() wants to defer a function call. So you have to pass a function:

Either:

```
_( function() { self.loadRemixedCollection(self.model); } ).defer();
```

Or

```
_( self.loadRemixedCollection ).defer(self.model);
```

Well, or

```
_.defer( function() { self.loadRemixedCollection(self.model); } )
_.defer( self.loadRemixedCollection, self.model )
```